# Read a file in C++ from a specific Line and then store it in Vectors/Array

Tags: c++, file, c++11, graph, stdvector

I am new to C++ programming and I did my homework for reading a file. I am learning C++ from this [cpp-tutorial: Basic-file-io](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/136-basic-file-io/) site.

I have a file whose content looks like:

```
Input: /path/to/the/file/
Information :xxx
Type of File: Txt file
Extra Information Value = 4
Development = 55
NId      CommId
1        0
3        0
8        7
.   .
And so on...
```

This file has about `10000 Nodes` and their corresponding `CommID`. The `Node and CommId` are seperated by `TAb space` in this file. I am reading this file as Input by using the following code:

```
ifstream commFile("CommTest.txt");
if (!commFile)
       {
         // Print an error and exit
    cerr << "Uh oh, CommunityTest File could not be opened for reading!" << endl;
                 exit(1);
             }
while(commFile)
{
    // read communityFile from the 6th Line
    string strLine;

    getline(commFile, strLine);
    cout << strLine << endl;

}
```

I have two questions:

> 1. I want to start reading from Line 7 i.e 1 0 and so on.
> 2. How can I start reading it from the line 7?

I checked lot of questions and came across that it is not possible to jump to line number if the lines of the txt files are of different length.

I wonder how to use seekg in which I need to count the bits before I can reach Line 7.

```
Please let me know, how to do it?
```

I want to get the Nodes and CommId in two seperate Integers. As soon as I have Node in an Integer, I want to search the Neighbour Nodes of this Node from a Graph file(This file is also provided as input and it has edges information). After getting the Neighbours of this Node, I want to store the collected Neighbours and their CommId (commId of every Node is available from the above file). I want to store them as pair in an Array/Vector.

For example:

> After reading 1   0 from this file. I will take the Node 1 and will
>   find the Neighbours of Node 1 from a Graph File. For every Neighbours
>   of Node 1, I want to save the information as a pair. For example, if
>   Node 1 has two Neighbours Node. i.e Node 63 and Node 55. If Node 63
>   belong to commId 100 and Node 55 belongs to CommId 101, the pair
>   should be:
>
> [(63,100),(55,101)..] and so on.

The learning link, STackOverflow forum suggested me to use Vectors,Map, STructs for Graphs. I haven't used Vector/Maps,Structs anytime before in my life. I am aware of Array as I used it before.

Please suggest what would be the best way.

Thanks in advance. Every help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You put a counter in the loop and skip processing the line read until the counter reaches to 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read text file from 7 no line by this:

```
for (int lineno = 0; getline (myfile,line) && lineno < 7; lineno++)
  if (lineno > 6)
      cout << line << endl;
```

after getting `NId and CommId` from #7 line, you can take it in stringstream. You can learn it from [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/)

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << line;
int nId,CId;
ss >> nId >> CId;
```

Then can take 2D array and I think you must handle 2D array which if

```
array[row][column]
```

Every `row` define as `NId` and corresponding in a row you and store `commId` as a `column` value.

according to your Example: [(63,100),(55,101)..] and so on.

```
Here NId 63, 55 .....
So you can..
array[63][0] = 100
array[55][0] = 101
so on....
```

You can do it by a `count` and handle column value like 0,1,2.....

Comment: Wow. That was a quick response. Thanks a lot for the reply and suggestion. I will try the suggested method and get back in case if I am facing some problem. Thanks a lot again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    vector<int> nodes;
    map<int, vector<int> > m;
    ifstream commFile("file.txt");
    string strLine, node_string;
    int node;
    if (!commFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Uh oh, CommunityTest File could not be opened for reading!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // Ignore the first lines of your file, deal with the empty lines
    for(int i = 0; i < 12 && std::getline(commFile,strLine); i++) {
        cout << "Line to ignore = " << strLine << endl;
    }

    while(getline(commFile,strLine)) {
        istringstream split(strLine);
        // split the string with your nodes
        while(getline(split, node_string, ' ')) {
            std::istringstream buffer(node_string);
            buffer >> node;
            // push it into a temporary vector
            nodes.push_back(node);
        }
        if(nodes.size() >= 2) {
            // add into your map
            m[nodes[0]].push_back(nodes[1]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```